# How to assign colors using plotTangentSpace

Tags: r

I am performing a PCA on my .tps file and I need to assign colors to species or specimens so that when plotting the graph (and the legend on it) colors do not overlap.

This is my current code:

```
prueba <- readland.tps("todos",specID = "ID")
ProPrueba <- gpagen(prueba) 
NameList <- dimnames(prueba)[[3]] 
UniqueNames <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', NameList)
dimnames(prueba)[[3]] <- UniqueNames 
factores <- factor(UniqueNames)
pca_prueba <- plotTangentSpace(ProPrueba$coords, label= NULL, verbose =T, 
groups=factores, warpgrids=F, legend = T)
```

Resulting in:

[image: plot]

Comment: Have you read this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geomorph/versions/3.0.7/topics/plotTangentSpace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.